# Java Swing Button not working

Tags: java, swing, button, background

So I'm making a program that prints out a square brick and a triangular roof. The panel has a background that shows the sky and some grass. Everything seems to be working fine except the buttons that work, when I click the brick button nothing happens. I've tried remodelling the code but no progress.
Here's the program code:

```
package someapp;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
/**
*
* @author Drew
*/
class Someapp extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
private Graphics land;
private JButton bricks;
private JButton roof;
JButton b1;
JLabel l1;
JLabel background;
public Someapp()
{
setTitle("Buil Your Dream Home");
setSize(400,400);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setVisible(true);

setLayout(new BorderLayout());
background=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Sharon   Umute\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\someapp\\src\\someapp\\blue-sky.png"));


add(background);
background.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
bricks=new JButton("Bricks");
roof=new JButton("Roof");
background.add(bricks);
background.add(roof);
bricks.addActionListener(this);
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Someapp frame=new Someapp();
    frame.setSize(1280, 735);
    frame.setLocation(40, 0);

    frame.createGUI();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle("Build Your Dream Home");

}



private void createGUI() throws IOException{
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Container window=getContentPane();
window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
window.add(new JPanelWithBackground("wIcon"));

BufferedImage wPic = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("blue-sky.png"));
JLabel wIcon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(wPic));
}



@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    {
    Graphics paper=background.getGraphics();
    paper.drawRect(500, 700, 100, 100);
    paper.setColor(Color.red);
}
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
//To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
}
```

Comment: `background.getGraphics();` is not how painting works in Swing and you should NEVER use it this.  Have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting should work in Swing

Comment: Your roof JButton "won't work" because you never add an ActionListener to it. Your bricks JButton won't work right because you're not drawing correctly. You should never use a Graphics object obtained from a component via `getGraphics()`.

Comment: Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!